# Table cell with nowrap overflows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and want to create a simple HTML `table`, where in the last column I have a 2-button group and a single separate button. I want this last cell to always keep this 3 buttons in one line, so I added the `text-nowrap` bootstrap class (which is a simple `white-space: nowrap`).

If the content of the other cell(s) is long enough, the content of the last cell will overflow horizontally, and I don't understand why. I'd expect that the rest of the table will shrink to make space for the non-wrapping cell.

Here is a demo to reproduce the issue: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/wWM2a9R8Mt)

Here is the markup.

```
<div style="width: 500px">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>Test text</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default"><span>A</span></button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning"><span>B</span></button>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success"><span>C</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

The button group `div` and the separate `button` are all `inline-block` elements, so the wrapping should work as expected IMO. What am I doing wrong?

Maybe this is not strictly related to bootstrap.

**UPDATE**

- I've updated the bootply, the link was a previous version, sorry
- Tested in latest Chrome and IE, the issue is almost the same in both.

**The cause and the workaround**

- I've realized that unwrapping the two buttons from the `btn-group` will result a correct layout, so I started to examine what actually the `btn-group` does.
- I've found that the `btn`s in the `btn-group` are floated, and this floating causes the bad layout. <del>Adding a `clearfix` class to the `btn-group` solves the issue.</del> No it actually doesn't, still researching...
- I will examine why the `float: left` is needed for bootstrap, it seems like the buttons in the group could be aligned by using purely `inline-block` without margin. I will check this in the `v4-alpha` code, and will also report this issue to bootstrap `v3`.

Comment: Glad you have found your way. Yes, floated content does not count towards the total portion a cell will get. From your example code, the width of the right hand column are counted as if the column has just one button. Adding clearfix however cancels float.

Comment: `btn-group` is intentionally set with float, so that no button will get off screen or rendered outside of it's container when overflow occur.

Answer (score 3):

The `<table class="table">` will fill 100% width of it's container. Column width are divided proportionally to the width of it's content.

When the left hand side claim bigger portion, the button column will fall "short".

When the left hand side has smaller portion, the buttons column will grow larger, thus making the buttons "move toward the center".

**To solve:** Set the width of the right hand colum with a fixed value. A total value of combined width of all three buttons: `width:125px`. As shown below:

```
<div style="width: 500px">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>Test text</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap" style="width:125px;">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default"><span>A</span></button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning"><span>B</span></button>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success"><span>C</span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

See: http://www.bootply.com/PGL6xCDgMz

This will set the width of the button column to a fixed value of 125px. So the left hand column will get the rest of any portion left.

**Update 1:** (according to questioner comments)

**- technique 1:**

```
<div style="width: 500px">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>Test text</td>
      <td class="text-nowrap">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default"><span>A</span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning"><span>B</span></button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success"><span>C</span></button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

**- technique 2:**

```
<div style="width: 500px">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>Test text</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default"><span>A</span></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning"><span>B</span></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-success"><span>C</span></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I can always set a fixed width for the column, but then the `nowrap` functionality wouldn't be needed at all. I use the `nowrap` to avoid the need of fixed width.

Comment: I am sorry, you did not mention that you are avoiding that in your question. Then you should wrap your button in a plain `<table>` or place them in cells because table rows are not wrapped while white-space are. I will update my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Actually I've just found the cause of the issue, and updated my post accordingly/

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Another One Also

```
td {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this one would definitely need the `fixed` layout mode, however, I don't want to have a `max-width`, not even a `width`. I just would like the content not to wrap, and the other colums to accomodate.

Answer (score 0):

Read futher information [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

```
table { table-layout:fixed; width:100%; }
```

Rather than using table-layout: fixed; for your table, you can use this trick to get a DIV to always take up the full space of a TD with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` functionality:

```
div { width: 0; min-width: 100%; }
```

The main trick is giving the width something other than auto/percent, and using a min-width of 100%;

```
 div { width: 0; min-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
table.myTable { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid #000; }

td.td1 { width: 100%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td2 { width: 100px; min-width: 100px; }
td.td3 { width: 150px; min-width: 150px; }

td.td4 { width: 50%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td5 { width: 50%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td6 { width: 150px; min-width: 150px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of `fixed` table-layout, however, I thought it's needed only if one would like to control overflow (like text overflow with ellipsis). I wouldn't have thought that it's needed for a *simple*  non-wrapping content. I didn't find any note about this at the link. Isn't there really other way? The fixed layout introduces some side effects AFAIK.

Comment: I don't need the ellipsis overflow functionality, and I wouldn't like to use fixed column widths, because that's why I use the `text-nowrap` mode, to avoid the need of fixed widths. Maybe you misunderstood something. Please check my updated bootply (if you haven't already), my question is simply why the last button overflows the blue row.

Comment: Actually I've just found the cause of the issue, and updated my post accordingly/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try It 
table { table-layout:fixed; width:100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm aware of `fixed` table-layout, however, I thought it's needed only if one would like to control overflow (like text overflow with ellipsis). I wouldn't have thought that it's needed for a *simple*  non-wrapping content. Isn't there really other way? The fixed layout introduces some side effects AFAIK.

Comment: Hi Samudrala : your code-only answer would be better with some context. For example, you could explain why using the `fixed` layout would be a good way to solve the questioner's problem; then it would be more useful to them, and also to other readers searching for answers to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **updated [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/HIPvT9B31Q)**

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
tr{
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex !important;
}

tr .text{
  flex: 3
}
tr .buttons{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px;">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color: blue;">
        <td class="text">Test text Test text Test text Test textTest text Test textTest text Test text</td>
        <td class="text-nowrap buttons">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><span>A</span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning"><span>B</span></button>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-success"><span>C</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Note**: Styles on the buttons are not reflected in the given code as they are from bootstrap. But will work in the **[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/HIPvT9B31Q)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually I wouldn't like to use flexbox (yet), and also, this seems to be kind of similar to using fixed width columns, which I wanted to avoid also.